# Why am i getting Unresolved dependencies path: org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.12:1.0.3

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm trying to start project in intelij idea by this [tutorial](https://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started-intellij-track/building-a-scala-project-with-intellij-and-sbt.html), but when i'm running my project i'm getting this warn and error

Here's logs:

```
[info] Loading settings from idea.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /root/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/root/.sbt/1.0/plugins/}global-plugins...
Waiting for lock on /root/.ivy2/.sbt.ivy.lock to be available...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /home/r/Документы/sbtExampleProject/project
[info] Updating {file:/home/r/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B/sbtExampleProject/project/}sbtexampleproject-build...
Waiting for lock on /root/.ivy2/.sbt.ivy.lock to be available...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to sbtExampleProject (in build file:/home/r/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B/sbtExampleProject/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/r/Документы/sbtExampleProject/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[info] Attempting to fetch org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.12:1.0.3.
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-sbt#compiler-bridge_2.12;1.0.3: 1
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] ## Exception when compiling 1 sources to /home/r/Документы/sbtExampleProject/target/scala-2.12/classes
[error] The compiler bridge sources org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.12:1.0.3:compile could not be retrieved.
[error] 
[error]     Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error]         org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.12:1.0.3
[error]           +- org.scala-sbt.temp:temp-module-98ec89c315ed408f615fff2c4774286d17323b01:1.0.3
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$3(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:262)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$3$adapted(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:252)
[error] sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:365)
[error] sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:372)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$2(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:252)
[error] scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error] sbt.internal.util.BufferedLogger.bufferQuietly(BufferedLogger.scala:106)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$1(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:252)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$1$adapted(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:249)
[error] sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:365)
[error] sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:372)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.compileAndInstall(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:249)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compiledBridgeJar$1(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:215)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IfMissing$Define.run(IfMissing.scala:19)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.createAndCache$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:46)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$3(ZincComponentManager.scala:57)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.getOrElse$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:38)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$2(ZincComponentManager.scala:57)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager$$anon$1.call(ZincComponentManager.scala:87)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
[error] xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error] xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lock(ZincComponentManager.scala:87)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$lockSecondaryCache$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:84)
[error] scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lockSecondaryCache(ZincComponentManager.scala:82)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.fromSecondary$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:55)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$6(ZincComponentManager.scala:61)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.getOrElse$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:38)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$5(ZincComponentManager.scala:61)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager$$anon$1.call(ZincComponentManager.scala:87)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
[error] xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error] xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lock(ZincComponentManager.scala:87)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lockLocalCache(ZincComponentManager.scala:78)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.files(ZincComponentManager.scala:61)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.file(ZincComponentManager.scala:66)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.compiledBridgeJar(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:215)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler$ZincCompilerBridgeProvider.compiledBridge(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:80)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler$ZincCompilerBridgeProvider.fetchCompiledBridge(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:87)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.loader(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:249)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.getInterfaceClass(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:267)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:234)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.newCachedCompiler(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:134)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.newCachedCompiler(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:121)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.FreshCompilerCache.apply(CompilerCache.scala:78)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:88)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:81)
[error] scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:132)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:72)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:115)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:305)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1$adapted(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:305)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.doCompile(Incremental.scala:101)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$4(Incremental.scala:82)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.recompileClasses(IncrementalCommon.scala:117)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:64)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$3(Incremental.scala:84)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:129)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:75)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:70)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileInternal(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:309)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileIncrementally$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:267)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.handleCompilationError(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:158)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:237)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compile(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:68)
[error] sbt.Defaults$.compileIncrementalTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:1403)
[error] sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1(Defaults.scala:1385)
[error] scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error] sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
[error] sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
[error] sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:257)
[error] sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error] sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:266)
[error] sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:257)
[error] sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:167)
[error] sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:32)
[error] java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error] java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
[error] java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error] java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
[error] java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
[error] java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
[error]            
[error] sbt.internal.inc.InvalidComponent: The compiler bridge sources org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.12:1.0.3:compile could not be retrieved.
[error] 
[error]     Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error]         org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.12:1.0.3
[error]           +- org.scala-sbt.temp:temp-module-98ec89c315ed408f615fff2c4774286d17323b01:1.0.3
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$3(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:262)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$3$adapted(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:252)
[error]     at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:365)
[error]     at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:372)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$2(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:252)
[error]     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.BufferedLogger.bufferQuietly(BufferedLogger.scala:106)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$1(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:252)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$1$adapted(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:249)
[error]     at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:365)
[error]     at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:372)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.compileAndInstall(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:249)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compiledBridgeJar$1(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:215)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IfMissing$Define.run(IfMissing.scala:19)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.createAndCache$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:46)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$3(ZincComponentManager.scala:57)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.getOrElse$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:38)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$2(ZincComponentManager.scala:57)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager$$anon$1.call(ZincComponentManager.scala:87)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lock(ZincComponentManager.scala:87)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$lockSecondaryCache$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:84)
[error]     at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lockSecondaryCache(ZincComponentManager.scala:82)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.fromSecondary$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:55)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$6(ZincComponentManager.scala:61)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.getOrElse$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:38)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$5(ZincComponentManager.scala:61)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager$$anon$1.call(ZincComponentManager.scala:87)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lock(ZincComponentManager.scala:87)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lockLocalCache(ZincComponentManager.scala:78)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.files(ZincComponentManager.scala:61)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.file(ZincComponentManager.scala:66)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.compiledBridgeJar(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:215)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler$ZincCompilerBridgeProvider.compiledBridge(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:80)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler$ZincCompilerBridgeProvider.fetchCompiledBridge(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:87)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.loader(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:249)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.getInterfaceClass(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:267)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:234)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.newCachedCompiler(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:134)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.newCachedCompiler(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:121)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.FreshCompilerCache.apply(CompilerCache.scala:78)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:88)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:81)
[error]     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:132)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:72)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:115)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:305)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1$adapted(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:305)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.doCompile(Incremental.scala:101)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$4(Incremental.scala:82)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.recompileClasses(IncrementalCommon.scala:117)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:64)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$3(Incremental.scala:84)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:129)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:75)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:70)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileInternal(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:309)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileIncrementally$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:267)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.handleCompilationError(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:158)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:237)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compile(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.Defaults$.compileIncrementalTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:1403)
[error]     at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1(Defaults.scala:1385)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:257)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:266)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:257)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:167)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:32)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) sbt.internal.inc.InvalidComponent: The compiler bridge sources org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.12:1.0.3:compile could not be retrieved.
[error] 
[error]     Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error]         org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.12:1.0.3
[error]           +- org.scala-sbt.temp:temp-module-98ec89c315ed408f615fff2c4774286d17323b01:1.0.3
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Nov 17, 2017, 11:24:08 AM\
```

My build.props:

```
sbt.version = 1.0.3
```

and build.sbt

```
name := "sbtExampleProject"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.6"
```

I think i have excatly the same code like in tutorial. I don't understand what a problem and how to relosve this dependencies. Sbt plugin is downloaded by idea and versions of scala and sbt are the same like in tutorial

**EDITED**

here's idea.log and sby.last.log [link](http://dropmefiles.com/Ps63i)

http://joxi.ru/YmEMpRQFZ6g9Em

Cannot find command sbt:
http://joxi.net/Q2KQqJKC9GQJNr

Comment: Could you please provide idea.log and sbt.last.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE  and reproducing the issue? Looks like an issue with ivy repo. Do you use any antivirus software?

Comment: @y.bedrov restarting of IDE not fixing the problem. I shared logs what you asked, hope it helps

Comment: Could you please also share screnshot of your SBT settings "Settings | Build | Build Tools | SBT" ?

Comment: Does it work from a terminal, like `sbt test:compile` does that resolve everything? In IntelliJ, try from the sbt window, "Refresh all SBT projects". If nothing helps, try wiping your caches - `rm -r  ~/.sbt/boot/`, or drastically `rm -r ~/.ivy2/cache/`; also perhaps `project/target/`; make sure you restart IntelliJ after that.

Comment: @y.bedrov added screen

Comment: Does it help if you enable "Use SBT shell..." option?

Comment: @y.bedrov no, it doesn't . Sorry for not replying so logn

Comment: Could you try it with clean installation (without importing settings) of 2017.3 EAP: jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion ?

Comment: @y.bedrov it doesn't help too:(

Comment: What about removing folders mentioned in previous comments?

Comment: @y.bedrov terminal writes that i it dont have command sbt, i added screen, how to whipe catch, where i have to write it? I can't do this in terminal and in sbt shell

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Please try to reinstall sbt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had faced the same problem by following that tutorial you mentioned. I am assuming that you are behind proxy.

so you need to add the **http** and **https** parameters in  **vm parameters**.

edit the following :
**Run -> edit Configurations -> sbt Task -> "Run the program" -> VM Parameters**

```
-Xms512M
-Xmx1024M
-Xss1M
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy_ip> #eg: 10.1.2.3
-Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxy port> #eg: 8080
-Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxy_ip> #eg: 10.1.2.3
-Dhttps.proxyPort=<proxy port> #eg: 8080
```

If you don't know the proxy address, try the below, 
open **chrome -> settings -> search proxy -> open proxy settings -> Lan Settings -> Proxy Server**..
there is a possible that you can find over there :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using JDK Version 1.8. I was facing the same problem while importing one of my old projects and changing the custom location to JDK Version 1.8 helped me.
The location of your JVM is dependent on what version of OSX you are using. On newer versions of OSX/macOS, you can use this command to find the location of the JDK `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`.

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me when I tried to compile a pretty old project that was still on SBT 1.1.0. Simply upgrading it to SBT 1.5.5 fixed the issue.