# sbt unable to create jar for scala version 2.11.12

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to create .jar file for simple hello world project using scala in intellij IDE (2019.3.2 community edition) with sbt build tool (version 1.3.8). I can do this without any issues for scala version 2.13.1. But when I am changing this to 2.11.12, sbt package is breaking with below error.
I wanted to add spark-core dependency as well to this project. So I have to use 2.11.12 version since there is not compatible version for 2.13.1.
Please help me with this error.

> [info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\username.sbt\1.0\plugins
>   [info] Loading project definition from
>   C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\scalawithsbt\project [info] Loading
>   settings for project scalawithsbt from build.sbt ... [info] Set
>   current project to scalawithsbt (in build
>   file:/C:/Users/username/IdeaProjects/scalawithsbt/) [info] Compiling 1
>   Scala source to
>   C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\scalawithsbt\target\scala-2.11\classes
>   ... Feb 14, 2020 11:48:15 AM
>   lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.shaded.org.jline.utils.Log
>   logr WARNING: Unable to create a system terminal, creating a dumb
>   terminal (enable debug logging for more information) [info] Attempting
>   to fetch org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.11:1.3.4. [info] Updating
>   [info] Resolved  dependencies [error] ## Exception when compiling 1
>   sources to
>   C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\scalawithsbt\target\scala-2.11\classes
>   [error] sbt.internal.inc.InvalidComponent: The compiler bridge sources
>   CoursierModuleDescriptor(ModuleDescriptorConfiguration(false, None,
>   org.scala-sbt.temp:temp-module-518b91374cbcb06003d475b7704c2316602396eb:1.3.4:co
>   mpile,
>   ModuleInfo(temp-module-518b91374cbcb06003d475b7704c2316602396eb, ,
>   None, None, Vector(), , None, None, Vector()),
>   Vector(org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.11:1.3.4:compile), Vector(),
>   Vector(), , Vector(compile, ru ntime, test, provided, optional),
>   Some(compile), ConflictManager(latest-revision, *,
>   *)),CoursierConfiguration(Some(sbt.internal.util.ManagedLogger@7306a11a),
>   Vector(Raw(ProjectResolver(inter-project, mapped: org.scala-
>   sbt#global-plugins;0.0)), public: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/,
>   FileRepository(local,
>   Patterns(ivyPatterns=Vector(///C:/Users/username/.ivy2//local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersio
>   n]/)([branch]/)[revision]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]),
>   artifactPatterns=Vector(///C:/Users/username/.ivy2//local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)([branch]/)[revision]
>   /[type]s/artifact.[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false,
>   descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false),
>   FileConfiguration(true, None)), URLRepository(sbt-plugin-releases,
>   Patterns(ivyPatterns=Vector(h
>   ttps://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)([branch]/)[revision]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]),
>   artifactPatterns=Vector(https://re
>   po.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)([branch]/)[revision]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]),
>   isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional
>   =false, skipConsistencyCheck=false), false), URLRepository(typesafe-alt-ivy-releases,
>   Patterns(ivyPatterns=Vector(https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtV
>   ersion]/)([branch]/)[revision]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]),
>   artifactPatterns=Vector(https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)([branch
>   ]/)[revision]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]),
>   isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false,
>   skipConsistencyCheck=false), false), sbt-maven-releases:
>   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/, sb
>   t-maven-snapshots:
>   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/,
>   URLRepository(typesafe-ivy-releases,
>   Patterns(ivyPatterns=Vector(https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/[organization]/[module]/[revision
>   ]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]),
>   artifactPatterns=Vector(https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]),
>   isMavenCompatible=false, d escriptorOptional=false,
>   skipConsistencyCheck=false), false), URLRepository(sbt-ivy-snapshots,
>   Patterns(ivyPatterns=Vector(https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/ar
>   tifact.[ext]),
>   artifactPatterns=Vector(https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]),
>   isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOp tional=false,
>   skipConsistencyCheck=false), false)), 6, 100, Some(org.scala-lang),
>   Some(2.12.10),
>   Vector(C:\Users\username.sbt\boot\scala-2.12.10\lib\jansi.jar,
>   C:\Users\username.sbt\boot\scala-2.12.10\lib\ jline.jar,
>   C:\Users\username.sbt\boot\scala-2.12.10\lib\scala-compiler.jar,
>   C:\Users\username.sbt\boot\scala-2.12.10\lib\scala-library.jar,
>   C:\Users\username.sbt\boot\scala-2.12.10\lib\scala-reflect .jar,
>   C:\Users\username.sbt\boot\scala-2.12.10\lib\scala-xml_2.12.jar),
>   Vector(), Vector(), Vector(), true, false, Vector(), Vector(),
>   Some(org.scala-lang), Some(2.11.12), Vector(), Vector(), None,
>   Some(C:\Users\ username\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1),
>   Some(C:\Users\username.ivy2), None, None, Vector(), Vector(),
>   Vector((ModuleMatchers(Set(), Set(), true),Relaxed)), true)) could not
>   be retrieved. [error] [error]         Note: Unresolved dependencies
>   path: [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincLMHelper$.update(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:293)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$3(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:257)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$3$adapted(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:250)
>   [error] sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:489) [error]
>   sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:499) [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$2(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:250)
>   [error]
>   scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.util.BufferedLogger.bufferQuietly(BufferedLogger.scala:119)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$1(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:250)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$1$adapted(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:247)
>   [error] sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:489) [error]
>   sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:499) [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.compileAndInstall(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:247)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compiledBridgeJar$1(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:215)
>   [error] sbt.internal.inc.IfMissing$Define.run(IfMissing.scala:19)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.createAndCache$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:49)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$3(ZincComponentManager.scala:60)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.getOrElse$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:42)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$2(ZincComponentManager.scala:60)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager$$anon$1.call(ZincComponentManager.scala:89)
>   [error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
>   [error]
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
>   [error]
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
>   [error] xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10) [error]
>   xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9) [error]
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
>   [error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50) [error]
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31) [error]
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28) [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lock(ZincComponentManager.scala:89)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$lockSecondaryCache$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:86)
>   [error] scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230) [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lockSecondaryCache(ZincComponentManager.scala:86)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.fromSecondary$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:58)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$6(ZincComponentManager.scala:64)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.getOrElse$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:42)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$5(ZincComponentManager.scala:64)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager$$anon$1.call(ZincComponentManager.scala:89)
>   [error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
>   [error]
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
>   [error]
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
>   [error] xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10) [error]
>   xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9) [error]
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
>   [error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50) [error]
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31) [error]
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28) [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lock(ZincComponentManager.scala:89)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lockLocalCache(ZincComponentManager.scala:82)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.files(ZincComponentManager.scala:64)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.file(ZincComponentManager.scala:70)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.compiledBridgeJar(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:215)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler$ZincCompilerBridgeProvider.compiledBridge(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:75)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler$ZincCompilerBridgeProvider.fetchCompiledBridge(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:81)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.loader(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:260)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.getInterfaceClass(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:278)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:245)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.newCachedCompiler(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:145)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.newCachedCompiler(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:132)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.FreshCompilerCache.apply(CompilerCache.scala:102)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:92)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$4(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:91)
>   [error]
>   scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:186)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:82)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3$adapted(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:77)
>   [error] sbt.internal.inc.JarUtils$.withPreviousJar(JarUtils.scala:215)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:77)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:146)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:343)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1$adapted(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:343)
>   [error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.doCompile(Incremental.scala:120)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$4(Incremental.scala:100)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.recompileClasses(IncrementalCommon.scala:180)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:98)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$3(Incremental.scala:102)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:155)
>   [error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:92)
>   [error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:75)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileInternal(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:348)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileIncrementally$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:301)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.handleCompilationError(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:168)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:248)
>   [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compile(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:74)
>   [error] sbt.Defaults$.compileIncrementalTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:1762)
>   [error]
>   sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1(Defaults.scala:1735)
>   [error] scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49) [error]
>   sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
>   [error] sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:67) [error]
>   sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:281) [error]
>   sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:19)
>   [error] sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:290) [error]
>   sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:281) [error]
>   sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
>   [error] sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
>   [error] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   [error]
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [error] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   [error]
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [error]
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [error] java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [error] [error]
>   sbt.internal.inc.InvalidComponent: The compiler bridge sources
>   CoursierModuleDescriptor(ModuleDescriptorConfiguration(false, None,
>   org.scala-sbt.temp:temp-module-518b91374cbcb06003d475b7704c2316602396eb:1.3.4:co
>   mpile,
>   ModuleInfo(temp-module-518b91374cbcb06003d475b7704c2316602396eb, ,
>   None, None, Vector(), , None, None, Vector()),
>   Vector(org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.11:1.3.4:compile), Vector(),
>   Vector(), , Vector(compile, ru ntime, test, provided, optional),
>   Some(compile), ConflictManager(latest-revision, *,
>   *)),CoursierConfiguration(Some(sbt.internal.util.ManagedLogger@7306a11a),
>   Vector(Raw(ProjectResolver(inter-project, mapped: org.scala-
>   sbt#global-plugins;0.0)), public: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/,
>   FileRepository(local,
>   Patterns(ivyPatterns=Vector(///C:/Users/username/.ivy2//local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersio
>   n]/)([branch]/)[revision]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]),
>   artifactPatterns=Vector(///C:/Users/username/.ivy2//local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)([branch]/)[revision]
>   /[type]s/artifact.[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false,
>   descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false),
>   FileConfiguration(true, None)), URLRepository(sbt-plugin-releases,
>   Patterns(ivyPatterns=Vector(h
>   ttps://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)([branch]/)[revision]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]),
>   artifactPatterns=Vector(https://re
>   po.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)([branch]/)[revision]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]),
>   isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional
>   =false, skipConsistencyCheck=false), false), URLRepository(typesafe-alt-ivy-releases,
>   Patterns(ivyPatterns=Vector(https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtV
>   ersion]/)([branch]/)[revision]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]),
>   artifactPatterns=Vector(https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)([branch
>   ]/)[revision]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]),
>   isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false,
>   skipConsistencyCheck=false), false), sbt-maven-releases:
>   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/, sb
>   t-maven-snapshots:
>   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/,
>   URLRepository(typesafe-ivy-releases,
>   Patterns(ivyPatterns=Vector(https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/[organization]/[module]/[revision
>   ]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]),
>   artifactPatterns=Vector(https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]),
>   isMavenCompatible=false, d escriptorOptional=false,
>   skipConsistencyCheck=false), false), URLRepository(sbt-ivy-snapshots,
>   Patterns(ivyPatterns=Vector(https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/ar
>   tifact.[ext]),
>   artifactPatterns=Vector(https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]),
>   isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOp tional=false,
>   skipConsistencyCheck=false), false)), 6, 100, Some(org.scala-lang),
>   Some(2.12.10),
>   Vector(C:\Users\username.sbt\boot\scala-2.12.10\lib\jansi.jar,
>   C:\Users\username.sbt\boot\scala-2.12.10\lib\ jline.jar,
>   C:\Users\username.sbt\boot\scala-2.12.10\lib\scala-compiler.jar,
>   C:\Users\username.sbt\boot\scala-2.12.10\lib\scala-library.jar,
>   C:\Users\username.sbt\boot\scala-2.12.10\lib\scala-reflect .jar,
>   C:\Users\username.sbt\boot\scala-2.12.10\lib\scala-xml_2.12.jar),
>   Vector(), Vector(), Vector(), true, false, Vector(), Vector(),
>   Some(org.scala-lang), Some(2.11.12), Vector(), Vector(), None,
>   Some(C:\Users\ username\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1),
>   Some(C:\Users\username.ivy2), None, None, Vector(), Vector(),
>   Vector((ModuleMatchers(Set(), Set(), true),Relaxed)), true)) could not
>   be retrieved. [error] [error]         Note: Unresolved dependencies
>   path: [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincLMHelper$.update(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:293)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$3(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:257)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$3$adapted(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:250)
>   [error]         at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:489)
>   [error]         at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:499)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$2(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:250)
>   [error]         at
>   scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.util.BufferedLogger.bufferQuietly(BufferedLogger.scala:119)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$1(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:250)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$1$adapted(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:247)
>   [error]         at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:489)
>   [error]         at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:499)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.compileAndInstall(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:247)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compiledBridgeJar$1(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:215)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.IfMissing$Define.run(IfMissing.scala:19) [error]
>   at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.createAndCache$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:49)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$3(ZincComponentManager.scala:60)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.getOrElse$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:42)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$2(ZincComponentManager.scala:60)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager$$anon$1.call(ZincComponentManager.scala:89)
>   [error]         at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95) [error]
>   at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
>   [error]         at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
>   [error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
>   [error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9) [error]
>   at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
>   [error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
>   [error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31) [error]
>   at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28) [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lock(ZincComponentManager.scala:89)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$lockSecondaryCache$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:86)
>   [error]         at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230) [error]
>   at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lockSecondaryCache(ZincComponentManager.scala:86)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.fromSecondary$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:58)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$6(ZincComponentManager.scala:64)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.getOrElse$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:42)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$5(ZincComponentManager.scala:64)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager$$anon$1.call(ZincComponentManager.scala:89)
>   [error]         at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95) [error]
>   at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
>   [error]         at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
>   [error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
>   [error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9) [error]
>   at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
>   [error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
>   [error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31) [error]
>   at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28) [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lock(ZincComponentManager.scala:89)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lockLocalCache(ZincComponentManager.scala:82)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.files(ZincComponentManager.scala:64)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.file(ZincComponentManager.scala:70)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.compiledBridgeJar(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:215)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler$ZincCompilerBridgeProvider.compiledBridge(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:75)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler$ZincCompilerBridgeProvider.fetchCompiledBridge(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:81)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.loader(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:260)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.getInterfaceClass(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:278)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:245)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.newCachedCompiler(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:145)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.newCachedCompiler(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:132)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.FreshCompilerCache.apply(CompilerCache.scala:102)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:92)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$4(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:91)
>   [error]         at
>   scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:186)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:82)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3$adapted(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:77)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.JarUtils$.withPreviousJar(JarUtils.scala:215) [error]
>   at
>   sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:77)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:146)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:343)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1$adapted(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:343)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.doCompile(Incremental.scala:120) [error]
>   at
>   sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$4(Incremental.scala:100)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.recompileClasses(IncrementalCommon.scala:180)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:98)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$3(Incremental.scala:102)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:155)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:92) [error]
>   at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:75)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileInternal(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:348)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileIncrementally$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:301)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.handleCompilationError(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:168)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:248)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compile(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:74)
>   [error]         at
>   sbt.Defaults$.compileIncrementalTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:1762) [error] 
>   at
>   sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1(Defaults.scala:1735)
>   [error]         at
>   scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49) [error]
>   at

Comment: Please, provide what dependencies do you have and versions in your project. Also the stack trace is not full `[error] at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49) 
[error] at` - I suspect something goes after it. Try to build jar not with IntelliJ but with sbt in command line, it most likely something is not compiling because of Scala 2.13

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention. I have to remove some part of error since its exceeding 30,000 characters limit. I am building code using `sbt package` command and the above error is coming up. I tried building and running with intellij buttons and it is working fine but I don't see .jar file in target location.
sbt version - 1.3.8
scala version - 2.11.12

Comment: What's your spark version ?

Comment: @rbcvl I haven't added spark yet in build.sbt. I am first trying to build scala code with 2.11.12 version and create a jar file out of this. This itself is failing.

Comment: "The compiler bridge sources... could not be retrieved", it says. Perhaps you're behind a firewall or proxy? Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47347713/why-am-i-getting-unresolved-dependencies-path-org-scala-sbtcompiler-bridge-2-1

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed.
I have two versions of java 8 running on my local.
After uninstalling the older version, I am able to switch between scala version and run

> sbt package

and create jars out of them.